# How to solve "float" object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this function where i'm doing a heat map and pass map for one player:

```
def heat_pass_map(data, player_name):
    pass_data = data[(data['type_name'] == "Pass") & (data['player_name'] == player_name)]
    action_data = data[(data['player_name']==player_name)]
    
    fig=plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(7, 5)
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    draw_pitch(ax)
    plt.axis('off')

    #passes
    for i in range(len(pass_data)):
        # we also differentiate different half by different color
        color = "blue" if pass_data.iloc[i]['period'] == 1 else "red"
        ax.annotate("", xy = (pass_data.iloc[i]['pass_end_location'][0], pass_data.iloc[i]['pass_end_location'][1]), xycoords = 'data', xytext = (pass_data.iloc[i]['location'][0], pass_data.iloc[i]['location'][1]), textcoords = 'data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="arc3", color = color))
      
    #heatmap
    x_coord = [i[0] for i in action_data['location']]
    y_coord = [i[1] for i in action_data['location']]
    sns.kdeplot(x = x_coord, y = y_coord, shade = "True", thresh = 0, cmap = "Greens", n_levels = 10)
    
    #create arrow legend
    blue_arrow = mlines.Line2D([], [], c='blue', marker=r'$\rightarrow$', markersize=15, linestyle='None', label='First half pass')
    red_arrow = mlines.Line2D([], [], c='red', marker=r'$\rightarrow$', markersize=15, linestyle='None', label='Second half pass')
    
    plt.ylim(0, 80) # need this, otherwise kde plot will go outside
    plt.xlim(0, 120)
    plt.legend(handles=[blue_arrow, red_arrow], loc='upper right')
    plt.title(str(player_name)+ "'s pass map")
    plt.show()
```

This function works fine for most of the players but now i saw trying to plot a map for some arab football players like: Mohammad Ibrahim Al Sahlawi

So, when I'm calling loading the data: ([click here for .json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/statsbomb/open-data/master/data/events/7525.json))

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Catalin\Desktop\WorldCupData\data\events\7525.json', encoding = 'utf-8') as data_file:    # r inainte de string ca sa il ia ca raw data
    data = json.load(data_file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, sep = "_")
heat_pass_map(df, 'Mohammad Ibrahim Al Sahlawi')
```

The following error occurs:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-52-b5a94966684b> in <module>
----> 1 heat_pass_map(df, 'Mohammad Ibrahim Al Sahlawi')

<ipython-input-49-5b6755070382> in heat_pass_map(data, player_name)
     16 
     17     #heatmap
---> 18     x_coord = [i[0] for i in action_data['location']]
     19     y_coord = [i[1] for i in action_data['location']]
     20     sns.kdeplot(x = x_coord, y = y_coord, shade = "True", thresh = 0, cmap = "Greens", n_levels = 10)

<ipython-input-49-5b6755070382> in <listcomp>(.0)
     16 
     17     #heatmap
---> 18     x_coord = [i[0] for i in action_data['location']]
     19     y_coord = [i[1] for i in action_data['location']]
     20     sns.kdeplot(x = x_coord, y = y_coord, shade = "True", thresh = 0, cmap = "Greens", n_levels = 10)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Expected results should look like this:
[image]

Comment: One of the expressions where you are using [] is a float where you are expecting a list or dictionary. Break the large expressions down into smaller ones to find out which one it is.

Comment: what is the reason for downvoting this question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your JSON, `action_data` looks something like

```
{
  ...
  "location" : [ 61.0, 40.0 ],
  ...
}
```

Now, we have

```
[i[0] for i in action_data['location']]
```

So for every `i` in `action_data['location']`, we're going to do something. `i`, in this case, will take on the values `61.0` and `40.0`. Now, the "something" we're doing is `i[0]`, so your list is going to be

```
[61.0[0], 40.0[0]]
```

Which is nonsense. If you want to extract the two values into `x_coord` and `y_coord`, you can just do

```
x_coord, y_coord = action_data['location']
```

and avoid the list comprehension altogether.

Comment: Hello, thank you for explanations. I tried to extract action_data['location'] values like you said, but it says "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". As another note, I saw that from some players, action_data it's something like [61.0 40.]...nan. Basically, the last element in this list is nan. For the players who doesn't have "nan" element in list works fine my part of code: "x_coord = [i[0] for i in action_data['location']]
    y_coord = [i[1] for i in action_data['location']]"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Some players had to be substituted and in .json file when sub was done location wasn't there, but in action_data was added (with NaN value) because I filtered all the data about that player. Below I will post the action_data updated:

```
action_data = data[(data['player_name']==player_name) & (data['type_name'] != 'Substitution')]
```